# Which .net version is used ? The one in web conifg or the one used while building?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, ssl

Probably a noob question but what version of .NET is used in a ASPX web application? Is it the version defined in the project propperties or the one defined in the web.config file of the website?

I need to know this because an API I am using in the web application is closing all non TLS1.2 protocolls. And as far as I understand TLS1.2 is the default in .NET 4.5. The server is Windows Server 2008.

Comment: If you update one does it not update the other?

Comment: @Shoe Well in my case this is not entirely true. I have one website with one web.config but with multiple asp.net projects. The web.config used is that of a third party system. The web.config on the webserver says version 4.0 is used. However I can use Interpolated Strings does that mean the visual studio version is used or are Interpolated Strings evaluated at compile time and compiled into something .net 4.0 understands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio uses web.config values to initialize the property pages.  So, they're one in the same.

You see the .NET version from the property pages in the web.config similar to this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you change the target framework in the project properties and save, you should see the updated target framework in that value in your web.config file.

Comment: Well in my case this is not entirely true. I have one website with one web.config but with multiple asp.net projects. The web.config used is that of a third party system. The web.config on the webserver says version 4.0 is used. However I can use Interpolated Strings does that mean the visual studio version is used or are Interpolated Strings evaluated at compile time and compiled into something .net 4.0 understands?

Comment: In ASP.NET applications, application config is "hierarchical".  Your subproject settings will override settings from higher levels in the application.

Comment: Also, the web.config on the server is what the production app will use.  Your project file is a MSBuild XML file.  It defines your app's (project's) settings.  Visual Studio just provides a GUI to modify those settings.  If you need different settings than what the third party web.config uses you'll need to create a separate (sub) application and override the higher level web.config settings.